# How to stock tooltip information into reactive variable in Shiny (R)

Tags: r, tooltip, shiny, ggvis

I built a Shiny App in order to display a ggvis scatter plot.
I managed to display "point characteristics" (labels, variables, etc.) by hovering mouse on it, using tooltip function.
My problem is that I want to put those "point characteristics" into a reactive variable.
My goal is to display the time serie plot corresponding to the point below the scatter plot.
Any Ideas?

here is my script for the ggvis graph :

```
  vis<-reactive({
    all_values <- function(x) {
      if(is.null(x)) return(NULL)
      paste0(names(x), ": ", format(x), collapse = "<br />")
    }

    xvar <- prop("x", as.symbol(input$variable))
    yvar <- prop("y", as.symbol(input$variable2))
    labvar <- prop("fill", as.symbol(input$vlabel))

    newdata %>%
      ggvis(x=xvar, y=yvar ) %>%
      layer_points(size := 50, size.hover := 200, fillOpacity := 1, fillOpacity.hover := 0.75,
                   fill=labvar, key:=~Code)%>%
      add_tooltip(all_values, "hover")%>%
      set_options(duration=500)

  })

  vis %>% bind_shiny ("plotggvis","plotggvis_ui")
```

Comment: can you provide some code